# Principle null congruences of Kerr metric

Tags: general-relativity, integration, geodesics, kerr-metric

I am trying to derive the principle null congruences of Kerr metric in Boyer-Lindquist coordinate, which is
$$t=r+\left( m+\frac{m^2}{(m^2-a^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}}\right)ln|r-r_+|+\left( m-\frac{m^2}{(m^2-a^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}}\right)ln|r-r_{-}|+constant $$
and
$$\phi=\left( \frac{a}{2(m^2-a^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}}\right)ln\left|\frac{r-r_{+}}{r-r_{+}}\right|+constant,$$ derived from equation
$$\frac{dt}{dr}=\frac{r^2+a^2}{\Delta}$$
and
$$\frac{d\phi}{dr}=\frac{a}{\Delta}$$
where $\Delta=r^2-2mr+a^2$ and $r_{\pm}=m\pm (m^2-a^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}$.

Here is my attempt,
$$\int \frac{r^2+a^2}{r^2-2mr+a^2}dr =\int \frac{r^2+r_{+}r_{-}}{r^2-r(r_{+}+r_{-})+r_{+}r_{-}}dr=\int dr+\int\frac{r(r_{+}+r_{-})}{r^2-r(r_{+}+r_{-})+r_{+}r_{-}}dr$$
$$=r+\frac{1}{2}r_{+}\int\frac{2r-(r_{+}+r_{-})}{r^2-r(r_{+}+r_{-})+r_{+}r_{-}}dr+\frac{1}{2}r_{-}\int\frac{2r-(r_{+}+r_{-})}{r^2-r(r_{+}+r_{-})+r_{+}r_{-}}dr+\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{(r_{+}+r_{-})^{2}}{r^2-r(r_{+}+r_{-})+r_{+}r_{-}}dr.$$
The last term should be a term of $tan^{-1}$ which doesn't appear in the solution. Could anybody show me the right process and tell me where is my mistake?

Comment: So far your derivation looks correct to me and indeed your conclusion is right as well: you did the separation in the right way and all steps as far as I can say are correct. It is interesting indeed by integrating it that way one would not be able to retrieve what should be the correct formula for $t$. It would be helpful if OP could provide the source which he/she is looking at, as there might be information missing in the question which may lead us to the correct answer.

Comment: Hint: Decompose the denominator of last integral as $(r-r_-)(r-r_{+})$, so again, this will give logarithmic terms (not $\tan ^{-1}$ term as you have mentioned). Once done, it should be straightforward to obtain the desired expression

Comment: @Rescy_ I am looking at D'Inverno's Introducing Einstein's Relativity Page 257.